# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed despite of defer_foreign_keys

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

In the following minimal example, we have a table that includes a self referencing foreign key. I want to use sqlite as my database with activated `PRAGMA foreign_keys`. To not care about the order of adding rows to the transaction, I'd like to set `PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = ON`.

The strange thing I discovered is, that this work well if I use in-memory sqlite, but it throws a "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" if I use a database file. What's going on here?

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, TYPE_CHECKING

import sqlalchemy.orm
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from sqlalchemy.pool import _ConnectionRecord  # noqa

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    parent_user_id = Column(ForeignKey("users.id"))


def main():
    # Using a database file, results in FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
    if Path("test_database.db").exists():
        Path("test_database.db").unlink()
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test_database.db")

    # Using in-memory works as expected
    # engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")

    @event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
    def set_sqlite_pragma(
        dbapi_connection: Any, connection_record: "_ConnectionRecord"
    ) -> None:
        if engine.name == "sqlite":
            cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
            cursor.close()

    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session = sqlalchemy.orm.Session(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

    user_1 = User(id=1, name="Bob", parent_user_id=2)
    user_2 = User(id=2, name="John Doe")

    session.add_all([user_1, user_2])
    session.execute("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = ON")
    session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.22.0'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1256, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 606, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/minimal_alchemy/example.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/minimal_alchemy/example.py", line 49, in main
    session.commit()
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1046, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2540, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2682, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2642, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 586, in execute
    persistence.save_obj(
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 239, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1083, in _emit_insert_statements
    c = cached_connections[connection].execute(statement, multiparams)
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1256, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "/home/finswimmer/tmp/minimal-alchemy/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 606, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
[SQL: INSERT INTO users (id, name, parent_user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ((1, 'Bob', 2), (2, 'John Doe', None))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
```

**UPDATE:**

There seems to be no problem using plain `sqlite3`:

```py
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path

table = """
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR, 
    parent_user_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(parent_user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
)
"""


def main():
    if Path("example.db").exists():
        Path("example.db").unlink()

    connection = sqlite3.connect("example.db")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(table)
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys=ON")

    users = [(1, "Bob", 2), (2, "John Doe", None)]
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?)", users)

    connection.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Workaround solution: Use a contextmanager to temporary disable foreign key checking and run `PRAGMA foreign_key_check` afterwards.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, TYPE_CHECKING

import sqlalchemy.orm
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from sqlalchemy.pool import _ConnectionRecord  # noqa

Base = declarative_base()


@contextmanager
def defer_foreign_keys(session: Session):
    if session.bind.name == "sqlite":
        session.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF")

        yield

        session.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")

        invalid_foreign_keys = session.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check").fetchall()
        if invalid_foreign_keys:
            msg = "\n".join(
                f"{invalid_key.table} (rowid: {invalid_key.rowid}) -> {invalid_key.parent}"
                for invalid_key in invalid_foreign_keys
            )
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid Foreign Keys detected: {msg}")


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    parent_user_id = Column(ForeignKey("users.id"))


def main():
    # Using a database file, results in FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
    if Path("test_database.db").exists():
        Path("test_database.db").unlink()
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test_database.db")

    # Using in-memory works as expected
    # engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")

    @event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
    def set_sqlite_pragma(
        dbapi_connection: Any, connection_record: "_ConnectionRecord"
    ) -> None:
        if engine.name == "sqlite":
            cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
            cursor.close()

    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session = sqlalchemy.orm.Session(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

    user_1 = User(id=1, name="Bob", parent_user_id=2)
    user_2 = User(id=2, name="John Doe")

    with defer_foreign_keys(session):
        session.add_all([user_1, user_2])
        session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```